# Subnet Masking vs Routing

Tags: networking, router, routing, subnet

To extend a network beyond the amount of 254 hosts, there are basically two options, if I understood it correctly:

- I could use a *second* network, having a different network prefix and connect the two networks with a router (or would that already require two routers?)
- I could remask the network to use a network prefix that allows more network addresses without the needs for a router, i.e. `255.255.254.0` (512 addresses) or `255.255.252.0` (1024 addresses)

Well, that's the theory so far. I have some questions on this:

**Subnetmasking**

If I would choose a subnet mask of `255.255.252.0` that would give me a network supporting 1024 adresses (ofc. minus the broadcast / network name adress) without routing, right?

How can I identify the actual network prefix? I mean, for a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`, it's obvious that the network ranges from `x.y.z.1` to `x.y.z.254` where I am completly free in choosing `x`, `y` and `z`.

How would that range look like for a `255.255.252.0` network?

From the binary represenation of the subnet mask `11111111.1111111.11111100.00000000` I would derive, that the valid adresses ranges from `x.y.252.1` to `x.y.255.254` - is that correct?

Do I have - with this subnetmask - any kind of influence on the second last number of the adress? I mean, could I setup the range from `x.y.0.1` to `x.y.3.254` as well? (*Fixed numbers due to first answer*)

(If yes: using `x.y.1.1` to `x.y.4.254` would **not** work I assume, cause `.4.` is part of another `/22` network than `.0.`, `.1.` and `.2.`, right?)

**Routing**

If I would use 4 routers to connect four `/24` networks, they still need to have different `Network-Prefixes`, right?

**Finally**

So, where is the actual difference between extending the subnetmask and connecting multiple networks using routers? (Except for the physical layout ofc.) Are there differences in terms of performance, or any other limitations?

Could a single DHCP (Windows Server) provide Adresses for a `/22` Network as well? Any drawbacks?

Comment: What you calculated is a single of a multitude of possible networks. The "masked" bits can change, too, after all. It’s just another network if they do.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I identify the actual network prefix? I mean, for a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, it's obvious that the network ranges from x.y.z.1 to x.y.z.254 where I am completly free in choosing x, y and z.

The same way as with 'regular' masks – using bitwise operations (`&` is AND, `|` is OR, `~` is NOT):

- network = address & mask *(all 0 bits in the mask must be 0 in the network address*)
- subnet broadcast = address | ~mask *(all 0 bits in the mask must be 1 in the broadcast address*)
- host addresses = [network+1 .. broadcast-1]

> From the binary represenation of the subnet mask 11111111.1111111.11111100.00000000 I would derive, that the valid adresses ranges from x.y.252.1 to x.y.255.254 - is that correct?
>
> Do I have - with this subnetmask - any kind of influence on the second last number of the adress? I mean, could I setup the range from x.y.1.1 to x.y.4.254 as well?

Basically, you can choose all bits that correspond to `1` in the mask. So in your example, you can choose any *z* as long as the last two bits (and all *t* bits) are zero, and this will be the *start* address. This gives you 64 different subnets with the same `x.y`: 192.168.0.0/22, 192.168.4.0/22, 192.168.8.0/22, and so on (ending at .3.255, .7.255, .15.255, and so on).

You're right that x.y.2.1 and x.y.5.254 will belong to separate subnets; x.y.0.0/22 and x.y.4.0/22 respectively. (But both would belong to the same x.y.0.0/21.)

> So, where is the actual difference between extending the subnetmask and connecting multiple networks using routers? (Except for the physical layout ofc.) Are there differences in terms of performance, or any other limitations?

[I'll leave this for someone else to answer.](https://superuser.com/posts/827898/edit)

> If I would use 4 routers to connect four /24 networks, they still need to have different Network-Prefixes, right?

Yes. You cannot route between two networks with the same prefix.

> Could a single DHCP (Windows Server) provide Adresses for a /22 Network as well?

Yes. All modern DHCP servers should let you configure any prefix length.

---

Tools like `ipcalc` or Python might be useful for generating a list of subnets:

```
>>> import ipaddress

>>> sub = ipaddress.IPv4Network("192.168.0.0/22")
>>> sub.network_address
IPv4Address('192.168.0.0')
>>> sub.broadcast_address
IPv4Address('192.168.3.255')

>>> sup = ipaddress.IPv4Network("192.168.0.0/16")
>>> list(sup.subnets(22-16))
[IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/22'), IPv4Network('192.168.4.0/22'),
 IPv4Network('192.168.8.0/22'), IPv4Network('192.168.16.0/22'),
 ...]
>>> for x in sup.subnets(22-16):
>>>     print(x)
192.168.0.0/22
192.168.4.0/22
192.168.8.0/22
...
```

Comment: Thanks so far - Ofc. you are right, the first network will be `.0.` to `.3.` - not as posted `.1.` to `.4.`